# Use of the cluster kmeans command in Stata

Tags: cluster-computing, stata, seed

I have a question about use of the `cluster kmeans` command in Stata.  I am using version 13 of the software.

I recognize that to obtain consistent groupings when using the `cluster` command, one must set the seed prior to the command.  My question is why, when I set different seeds and run the same `cluster` command, the groupings produced are completely different in composition from one another?  I gather this by running a cross tab of one on the other, e.g. `tab _clus_1 _clus_2`, where each clustering was generated after a different set seed, and see many cases grouped differently.

Since I know little about the algorithm that the `cluster` command is using, this causes me concern over the robustness of the grouping variable that is being created.  I am using a dataset of 616 observations and feed the cluster command 41 variables, many of which are either dummies (0/1), or within a range between 0 and 1, so I wondered if this lack of variation may be contributing to the very different groupings generated each time I set the seed at a different number.

Comment: This is more about statistics than about programming, but very simply if you can't get (nearly) repeatable clusterings, cluster analysis is likely to be pointless. The use of 0-1 variables, on the other hand, should make clustering easier, not more difficult. On a related note, questions without code are widely regarded of off-topic in this forum and are better directed at Cross-Validated.

Comment: Because you mentioned your unfamiliarity with the algorithm, I'd like to note that the cluster labels are completely arbitrary. Running kmeans many times and getting a different label for a case each time doesn't mean that the clustering is different, just that a different arbitrary label has been assigned. The only thing that is informative is the group of cases within each label. I apologize if this is too obvious

Answer (score 0):

If the variables you are clustering are all binary or factor variables, you might find a more stable solution using latent class clustering.

Stata can perform latent class analysis through (1) the `gllamm` program by Sophia Rabe-Hesketh and available on SSC from within Stata, or (2) the LCAplugin for Stata at http://methodology.psu.edu/downloads/lcastata, which is only available for the Windows platform.

Although the LCAplugin is not designed to work with Stata/IC due to maximum matrix size limits (i.e., 800), it should work for your problem, since you only have 616 cases and 41 variables if you `set matsize 800`.  If you have a higher flavor of Stata (e.g., SE or MP), the LCAplugin should not be bothered with those maximum matrix size limitations.